# Why does my object not get inserted into std::set?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following struct for comparing Rect object's..

```
struct rectcomp {
    bool operator() (const Rect& lhs, const Rect& rhs) const{
        return lhs.size.width<rhs.size.width;
    }
};
```

I have the following set where I wish to store my Rect's

```
std::set<Rect,rectcomp> _availableRects;
```

I insert it with the following code;

```
void insertPairOfRects(const Rect rect1,const Rect rect2){
    _availableRects.insert(rect1); //first line
    _availableRects.insert(rect2); //second line
}
```

The problem is, that rect1 always gets inserted, but rect2 doesn't. When I step through the debugger, after the first line of the function insertPairOfRects, I can clearly see the increase in number of objects in insertPairOfRects....but for the second I can't.

What mistake am I making ?

EDIT: I suspect it is because of a mistake in my comparator function. I have never written one before for a set, so I imagine it is probably a fundamental misunderstanding here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to assume that `rect1.size.width == rect2.size.width`, this makes the comparator return false for both cases in which case the object doesn't get inserted into the set because a set doesn't allow duplicates. Either change your rectangles or make a more detailed comparator.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. You are correct. I can accept your answer in 7 minutes..